# Find one user then get their ranking based on their total points using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ranking

So I got the following data:

Users collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("62a2a0422ec90fea68390aaa"),
  name: 'Robert Yamashita',
  username: 'robyama',
  email: 'robert.yamashita@rocketmail.com',
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("62a2a0452ec90fea68390aad"),
  name: 'Charles X',
  username: 'cvx',
  email: 'charles.xxx@rocketmail.com',
}
```

Points collection

```
{
  userId: ObjectId("62a2a0422ec90fea68390aaa"),
  action: 'Liked a post',
  points: 10,
}
{
  userId: ObjectId("62a2a0422ec90fea68390aaa"),
  action: 'Liked a post',
  points: 10,
}
{
  userId: ObjectId("62a2a0452ec90fea68390aad"),
  action: 'Liked a comment',
  points: 5,
}
```

I created a pipeline to get the total points of username *robyama* using the following query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: 'robyama' } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'points',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'user',
      as: 'userPoints'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$userPoints'
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: '$name',
        email: '$email',
        username: '$username',
      },
      count: { $sum: '$userPoints.points' }
    }
  }
]);
```

I got the following result:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "name": "Robert Yamashita",
    "email": "robert.yamashita@rocketmail.com",
    "username": "robyama",
  },
  "count": 20
}
```

This is exactly what I needed but I wanted to add a ranking field to the returned query since Robert has 20 points and Charles only has 5. So ideally I want the result to be this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "name": "Robert Yamashita",
    "email": "robert.yamashita@rocketmail.com",
    "username": "robyama",
  },
  "count": 20
  "rank": 1
}
```

What should I add to my pipeline to get the above output? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To get a `rank`ing by `"points"`, you'll need to aggregate all points for each user, yes?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, but I'm not sure how to do this. I need to get the ranking based on the sum of the total points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is one way of doing it.

1. Perform join using `$lookup` and calculate counts for each user.
2. Sort the elements by counts in desc order.
3. Group documents by `_id` as NULL and push them all in an array.
4. Unwind the array, along with getting row numbers.
5. Find your required document and calculate the rank using row number.

   ```
   db.users.aggregate([
   {
   $lookup: {
     from: "points",
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "userId",
     as: "userPoints"
   }
   },
   {
   $unwind: "$userPoints"
   },
   {
   $group: {
     _id: {
       name: "$name",
       email: "$email",
       username: "$username",

     },
     count: {
       $sum: "$userPoints.points"
     }
   }
   },
   {
   "$sort": {
     count: -1
   }
   },
   {
   "$group": {
     "_id": null,
     "docs": {
       "$push": "$$ROOT",

     }
   }
   },
   {
   "$unwind": {
     path: "$docs",
     includeArrayIndex: "rownum"
   }
   },
   {
   "$match": {
     "docs._id.username": "robyama"
   }
   },
   {
   "$addFields": {
     "docs.rank": {
       "$add": [
         "$rownum",
         1
       ]
     }
   }
   },
   {
   "$replaceRoot": {
     "newRoot": "$docs"
   }
   }
   ])
   ```

This is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SaiI2KYyni8).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it.  There's only one `"$lookup"` with one embedded `"$group"` so it should be fairly efficient.  The `"$project"` seems a bit contrived, but it gives the output in the format you want.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "username": "robyama"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "points",
      "as": "sortedPoints",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "count": {"$sum": "$points"}
          }
        },
        {"$sort": {"count": -1}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$sortedPoints",
      "includeArrayIndex": "idx"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": ["$_id", "$sortedPoints._id"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$name",
        "username": "$username",
        "email": "$email"
      },
      "count": "$sortedPoints.count",
      "rank": {
        "$add": ["$idx", 1]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hib2K-NdtZd).